# Getting Simplemodal to work responsively

Tags: responsive-design, modal-dialog, simplemodal

I have managed to get [simplemodal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) working--very happy with it--but I would like to get it working responsively; any suggestions? On smaller viewports the modal-window extends out of the viewport. Have I missed something in the options that already does what I want?

Alternatively what can I do with smaller viewports? Turn it off?

Comment: Okay I'm going to try media queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get the modals to work so I have relied on the fall back I alreay put in place for no js. Quite simply I'm turning the modals off when the screen size becomes troubling.

```
(function() {
  if (viewport.width() >= 705) {
    modal code here
  }
}());
```